# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable error in python when using the (int()) function

Tags: python

I have a problem in my code  where what I understand is that I have defined "int" as something such as
`int = ("random thing")`

My full code is The following if you need any more information

```
import sys



info = False
digit1 = 0
digit2 = 0
digit3 = 0
digit4 = 0
digit5 = 0
digit6 = 0
digit7 = 0
digit8 = 0
info = (bool(input("do you want extra info? (If not leave blank if yes enter anything)")))

input = (int(input("number from 0-255")))
if (int(input)) > (255):
    sys.exit("Wrong")



if input >= 128:


    input = input - 128
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 128")
        print("New number:")
        print(input)
    digit1 = 1

if input >= 64:

    input = input - 64
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 64")
        print("New number:")
        print(input)
    digit2 = 1

if input >= 32:

    input = input - 32
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 32")
        print("New number:")
        print(input)
    digit3 = 1
if input >= 16:

    input = input - 16
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 16")
        print("New number:")
        print(input)
    digit4 = 1
if input >= 8:

    input = input - 8
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 8")
        print("New number:")
        print(input)
    digit5 = 1
if input >= 4:

    input = input - 4
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 4")
        print("New number:")
        print(input)
    digit6 = 1
if input >= 2:

    input = input - 2
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 2")
        print("New number:")
        print(input)
    digit7 = 1
if input >= 1:

    input = input - 1
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 1")
        print("New number:")
        print(input)
    digit8 = 1
print("Your Input In binary is:")
output = (str(digit1) + str(digit2) + str(digit3) + str(digit4) + str(digit5) + str(digit6) + str(digit7) + str(digit8))
print (output)



digit01 = 0
digit02 = 0
digit03 = 0
digit04 = 0
digit05 = 0
digit06 = 0
digit07 = 0
digit08 = 0


input2 = (int(input("number from 0-255")))
if (int(input2)) > (255):
    sys.exit("Wrong")



if input2 >= 128:


    input2 = input2 - 128
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 128")
        print("New number:")
        print(input2)
    digit01 = 1

if input2 >= 64:

    input2 = input2 - 64
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 64")
        print("New number:")
        print(input2)
    digit02 = 1

if input2 >= 32:

    input2 = input2 - 32
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 32")
        print("New number:")
        print(input2)
    digit03 = 1
if input2 >= 16:

    input2 = input2 - 16
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 16")
        print("New number:")
        print(input2)
    digit04 = 1
if input2 >= 8:

    input2 = input2 - 8
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 8")
        print("New number:")
        print(input2)
    digit05 = 1
if input2 >= 4:

    input2 = input2 - 4
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 4")
        print("New number:")
        print(input2)
    digit06 = 1
if input2 >= 2:

    input2 = input2 - 2
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 2")
        print("New number:")
        print(input2)
    digit07 = 1
if input2 >= 1:

    input2 = input2 - 1
    if info == (True):
        print ("above 1")
        print("New number:")
        print(input2)
    digit08 = 1
print("Your Input In binary is:")
output2 = (str(digit01) + str(digit02) + str(digit03) + str(digit04) + str(digit05) + str(digit06) + str(digit07) + str(digit08))
print (output2)



a = output
b = output2
max_len = max(len(a), len(b))
a = a.zfill(max_len)
b = b.zfill(max_len)

result = ''

carry = 0

for i in range(max_len - 1, -1, -1):
    r = carry
    r += 1 if a[i] == '1' else 0
    r += 1 if b[i] == '1' else 0
    result = ('1' if r % 2 == 1 else '0') + result

    carry = 0 if r < 2 else 1

if carry != 0:
    result = '1' + result

print(result.zfill(max_len))
```

Yes I know there's better ways of doing what I'm doing with this code but my output is this

```
do you want extra info? (If not leave blank if yes enter anything)
number from 0-255 *1*
Your Input In binary is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\10bam\Desktop\calculador\.idea\calc.py", line 105, in <module>
    input2 = (int(input("number from 0-255")))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
00000001

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And I'm understanding that I have bound something to `int` from what I've read but I have checked and that's not the case

Comment: You have a line `input = (int(input("number from 0-255")))` and some time after you have `input2 = (int(input("number from 0-255")))`. You are *"calling"* `input` but you changed it to be an int...

Comment: Function- and non-function-valued variables share the same namespace; `input` is simply a name that is *initially* bound to a built-in function. You can't define a separate variable with the same name; assigning to `input` simply replaces the function with a new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't bind `int` to anything else, but `input`. You bind `input` to an integer in line 16:

```
input = (int(input("number from 0-255")))
```

And then you try to use `input` as a function call in line 105:

```
input2 = (int(input("number from 0-255")))
```

At this time, your global namespace dictionary contains the key value pair `'input': 0`. Python will not search the `input` function in `builtins`, but directly take the value of `input` from the global namespace dictionary and call it, so you get the error.

To solve the problem, please rename the variable `input`, and remember not to let your variable have the same name as the built-in function.